# gridview with multi select listbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, listbox

HiI have a list box that is bound to a table in a database. it produces a list of companies. The user will then come along and select multiple companies that they want to view information about, and then they hit a selet button which ill display the company information (e.g company name, company site, address e.t.c) in a gridview underneath. however the issue that i am having is that it only displays ONE of the multiple companies selected and its always the top one.

Can someone please shed some light on how i get all the companies to be displayed in the gridview?

i am programming in vb.net

please see source code below

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource11" DataTextField="compName" 
        DataValueField="compDataID" SelectionMode="Multiple" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:ListBox>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource11" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IWSRiskAssessmentConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [compDataID], [compName] FROM [tblCompany] WHERE ([compDataID] &lt;&gt; @compDataID) ORDER BY [compName]">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="compDataID" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:GridView 
        ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="compName" HeaderText="compName" 
                SortExpression="compName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Site Name" HeaderText="Site Name" 
                SortExpression="Site Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Reference Number" HeaderText="Reference Number" 
                SortExpression="Reference Number" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Asset" HeaderText="Asset" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="Asset" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" 
                SortExpression="Location" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Block" HeaderText="Block" SortExpression="Block" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Room" HeaderText="Room" SortExpression="Room" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IWSRiskAssessmentConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT tblCompany.compName, tblSite.siteName AS [Site Name], tblSite.siteUPRN AS [Reference Number], tblIncMain.incAsset + ' ' + CAST(tblIncMain.incNumber AS varchar) AS Asset, tblIncMain.incLocation AS Location, tblIncMain.incBlock AS Block, tblIncMain.incRoom AS Room FROM tblIncMain INNER JOIN tblSite ON tblIncMain.incSite = tblSite.siteID INNER JOIN tblCompany ON tblSite.siteCompany = tblCompany.compDataID WHERE (tblIncMain.incActive = 1) AND (tblSite.siteActive = 1) AND (tblIncMain.incRemoved = 0) AND (tblCompany.compDataID = @compDataID) ORDER BY [Site Name], tblIncMain.incAsset, tblIncMain.incNumber">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListBox1" Name="compDataID" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

this is the source code :-) please take a look and any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You should provide sorce-code, otherwise we cannot see what's wrong. Where and how are you binding the GridView to it`s DataSource?

Comment: my question has been edited and i have added source code thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be DataBind code executes on every request or you are not collecting selected items from the listbox.

```
  Sub page_load()
     if Not IsPostBack Then

     End If
   End sub
```

and to iterate Listbox items,

```
For Each item in ListBox1.Items
  if item.Selected then
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data source is only selecting 1 record. The `ListBox` will return the first value when you use a multiple select `ListBox` as a `ControlParameter`.

```
(tblCompany.compDataID = @compDataID)
```

What you want to do is have something with an `IN` statement such as

```
(tblCompany.compDataID in @compData)
```

You may need to do something in the code behind.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" 
        AutoPostBack="True"
        DataTextField="compName" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource11"
        DataValueField="compDataID"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"
        SelectionMode="Multiple">
</asp:ListBox>
```

Code behind

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string s = string.Empty;
  foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
  {
    if (li.Selected == true)
      s += li.Value + ",";
  }

  if (s != string.Empty)
  {
    s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 2); // chop off trailing ,
    SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["compData"].DefaultValue = s;
  }  
}
```

**NOTE** this hasn't been tested but it is one option you can try. Basically you want a `IN` not a `=` for your select to get all results.

Comment: hi many thanks for this but when i attempt to select a company from the list box i get this error

Incorrect syntax near '@compDataID'

Comment: Hard to say what the issue is without seeing your source code. It sounds like there is an error in the SQL query. Your best bet to fix this is to print out the final sql statement and see where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

ok so i added 'in' to my sql statement, however it still only picked up one selection from the list box instead of multiple this is the sql statement:

```
SELECT tblCompany.compName, tblSite.siteName AS [Site Name], tblSite.siteUPRN AS [Reference Number], tblIncMain.incAsset + " " + CAST(tblIncMain.incNumber AS varchar) AS Asset, tblIncMain.incLocation AS Location, tblIncMain.incBlock AS Block, tblIncMain.incRoom AS Room FROM tblIncMain INNER JOIN tblSite ON tblIncMain.incSite = tblSite.siteID INNER JOIN tblCompany ON tblSite.siteCompany = tblCompany.compDataID WHERE (tblIncMain.incActive = 1) AND (tblSite.siteActive = 1) AND (tblIncMain.incRemoved = 0) AND tblCompany.compDataID in(@compDataID) ORDER BY [Site Name], tblIncMain.incAsset, tblIncMain.incNumber
```